# Update query in Java JDBC mysql doesn't work

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

The update query and the delete query don't work, only the select and the insert.

```
public static void updateQuery(String date) throws SQLException{ 
    String query = "update parks set flag=? where nick=? and day=?";
    PreparedStatement ps = mia.connect.prepareStatement(query);

    ps.setString(1,"y");
    ps.setString(2,user.getNickname());
    ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(date));
    ps.executeUpdate();
}

public static void deleteQuery(String date) throws SQLException{
    String query = "delete from parks where nick=? and day=?";
    PreparedStatement ps = mia.connect.prepareStatement(query);

    ps.setString(1,user.getNickname());
    ps.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(date));
    ps.execute();
}

public static void insert(int id_park,int weightTrip,LocalDate date,int during,int time) throws SQLException{

    // take the price
    int fullPrice = calculatePrice(id_park);
    frullPrice = fullPrice*during;
    String query = "insert into parks(numberID,nick,idpark,price,during,time,day,weithtrip,flag) " +
            "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = mia.connect.prepareStatement(query);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = 0;
    value = rand.nextInt((999 - 1) + 1) + 1;

    ps.setInt(1,value);
    ps.setString(2,user.getNickname());
    ps.setInt(3,id_park);
    ps.setInt(4,fullPrice);
    ps.setInt(5,during);
    ps.setInt(6,time);
    ps.setDate(7, Date.valueOf(date));
    ps.setInt(8,weightTrip);
    ps.setString(9,"n");

    ps.execute();
}
```

this is the actionListener on the button that calls the Procedure. (the
 delete is the same but instead of 'DBOperations.updateQuery' there is      'DBOperation.deleteQuery')

```
  submitButton.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                DBOperations.updateQuery(dateOfThePayment);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"thanks !");
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    });


     this is the table :
     create table parks (
     numberID integer not null,
     nick varchar(10) not null,
     idpark int not null,
     price int,
     during int,
     time int,
     day date,
     weighttrip int,
     flag varchar(1),
         )
```

These queries don't give me any error. The problem is that they don't do their job.
If I execute the same query on the command line they works well.

Comment: what is `mia` in your prepared statement, also in your update query `datePay` ?

Comment: And in your delete query put `ps.executeUpdate()` instead of `ps.execute()`

Comment: Show us the `select` and `insert` that you claim works, and show us the table definition, i.e. the `create table`.

Comment: mia is the name of a variable. the variable is the object of the connection (singleton).  sorry I didn't mention it. and datePay was I error in writing the question on the site.

Comment: Can you explain more "_The problem is that they don't do their job._". Are you sure you don't catch the exception and/or rollback the transaction? There is no try/catch in what we see. Hard to tell without the part that call these methods.

Comment: "The problem is that they don't do their job" means that these queries don't work, don't update the row and don't delete the row. I wrote the try/catch in the class that calls those procedure.

Comment: What does `user.getNickname()` have in it, print it and see onces

Comment: Sorry I'm Italian I translate some words in English to make more legible for you.

Comment: What does it have, print it and see ?

Comment: You should .close() your statements and not perform database interaction in the GUI thread.

Comment: what should I close ? and do you think i should insert an intermediate class ? like M.V.C. ?

Comment: You should `.close()` the `PreparedStatement` objects.

Comment: I solved it closing all the PreparedStatement. Thank you a lot !